# Does $x_i \to x$ and $y_i^* \overset{w^*}{\rightarrow} y^*$ imply $ \nabla F(x_i)^* y_{i}^* \overset{w^*}{\rightarrow} \nabla F(x_0)^* y^* $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $F: X \to Y$ be a continuously differentiable function between banach spaces $X$ and $Y$. (we also can assume $X$ is reflexive space) Let $x_0 \in X$, this tells us the derivative $\nabla F(x_0) \in B(X, Y)$ is a bounded linear operator, this is also true for adjoint-derivative i.e., $\nabla F(x_0)^* \in B(Y^* , X^*)$. 
My question is that if we have convergent nets $x_i \to x_0$ and $y_i^* \overset{w^*}{\rightarrow} y^*$ in $X$ and $Y^*$ respectively then do we have 
$$   \nabla F(x_i)^* y_{i}^*  \overset{w^*}{\rightarrow}  \nabla F(x_0)^* y^*  \in X^*     $$

My thought: I think $ G(x) = \nabla F(x)^*$ in norm to norm, continuous as $H(x) = \nabla F(x) $ is norm to norm continuous because $F$ is continuously Frechet differentiable. Then we can get the result from Uniform boundedness.

Comment: Do you have $x_i \to x$ or $x_i \to x_0$ after all ? Anyway, by the usage of duality brackets this can be checked easily.

Comment: Thanks. It is $x_0$