# Is $ G(x) = \nabla F(x)^* $ continuous when is $F$ continuously differentiable in Frechet's sense?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $F: X \to Y$ be a continuously differentiable function between banach spaces $X$ and $Y$(we also can assume $X$ is reflexive space) Let $x_0 \in X$, this tells us the derivative $\nabla F(x_0) \in B(X, Y)$ is a bounded linear operator, this is also true for adjoint-derivative i.e., $\nabla F(x_0)^* \in B(Y^* , X^*)$. 
My question:   Is the function $ G(x) = \nabla F(x)^* $ is norm to norm continuous ?

Comment: What is your definition of 'continuously differentiable function'? Is $x \to \nabla F(x)$ norm to operator norm continuous?

Comment: Yes, everything is in terms of norm. @KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\|x_n-x\| \to 0$ the $\|\nabla F(x_n)-\nabla F(x)\|\to 0$ which implies $\|G(x_n)-G(x)\| \to 0$.

Comment: Why exactly  $ \|G(x_n)-G(x)\| \to 0 $?

Comment: Because it is generally true that $\|T_n-T\| \to 0$ implies $\|T_n^{*}-T^{*}\| \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks, can it be concluded from Banach-Steinhaus' Theorem ?
btw do you have any idea about this question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3267194/219176

Comment: The fact that $\|T\|=\|T^{*}\|$ can be proved from definition of the adjoint and the definition of operator norm. There is no need to use Uniform Boundedness Principle.